# How can I access a logging block in CANoe configuration with the help of python COM?

Tags: python, vector, com, win32com, canoe

I want to get access to the logging block of a CANoe configuration from the Python COM. I want to use the status of the logging block to start and stop the measruement of test modules.

I have tried to read the help documentation in the CANoe for logging COM object, but I am little confused and cannot get the required answer as I am new to CANoe.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Which "status" do you want to access?

Comment: I want to check whether at any given time a specific logging block inside the measurement setup is active or not active.